# I want to move win10 storage spaces (configured as raid0 mirror) to new pc

Tags: hard-drive, raid

I have storage pool on windows PC (2x4tb drives one inetrnal SATA one external USB - configured in raid 0 - mirror). I am buying a new system - can and should I move the pool or try to start from scratch (ie copy the data to a third drive and format the pool drives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage Spaces pools are self-contained and independent from the creating system. As soon as you connect the drives and they are recognized as a pool, they should work exactly the same as before.