# How to move a Storage Space to a new computer?

Tags: windows, raid, storage-spaces

Previously, I had installed Windows 11 Pro on a 240GB boot SSD.  In addition to the boot SSD, I also had 4x1TB disks connected, configured in Windows as a Storage Spaces RAID5 pool.  My boot drive then failed and had to be replaced.

I assumed that I'd just be able to reinstall to a new SSD and have Windows [automatically detect the array](https://superuser.com/questions/1447370/i-want-to-move-win10-storage-spaces-configured-as-raid0-mirror-to-new-pc), but that doesn't seem to be true for me.  Windows doesn't show the array under This PC anymore, and `Get-StoragePool` doesn't pick up on the pool either.
[image: powershell diagnostics]
What can I do to get my data back?

Comment: Try PowerShell [Repair-SpacesConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storagespaces/repair-spacesconfiguration?view=winserver2012r2-ps).